# The way oracle calculate mod(binary_float, 0)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle document (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm#i77996) says that "MOD returns the remainder of n2 divided by n1. Returns n2 if n1 is 0.". But I got an unexpected result (I thought it should be 1.1 but I got 0) when I put a binary_float in n2.

```
SQL> select mod(1.1,0), to_binary_float('1.1'), mod(to_binary_float('1.1'), 0) from dual;

MOD(1.1,0) TO_BINARY_FLOAT('1.1') MOD(TO_BINARY_FLOAT('1.1'),0)
---------- ---------------------- -----------------------------
       1.1               1.1E+000                             0
```

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Sorry for my misleading expression. It's not a real error thrown by oracle. It's an unexpected return value. I got 0 rather than 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.  I think it has something to do with FLOOR vs ROUND used internally in the calculations.

For example, the REMAINDER function is very similar to mod, except is uses ROUND instead of FLOOR.  For this example, it will return NAN (not a number):

```
select remainder(to_binary_float(1.1), 0) from dual
```

Output:

```
NAN
```

Whats more interesting is that I can use NANVL function to provide a default value if NAN is returned (in this case, mimic the MOD behavior and return 1.1), and it will return a float value:

```
select nanvl(remainder(to_binary_float(1.1), 0), 1.1) from dual
```

Output:

```
1.10000002384186
```

So perhaps thats your workaround.

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you for the Answer! You provided a good alternative for my particular scenario, so I gave my credit for your answer. But I would like to keep this question open, as I want to know the root cause.